# WindowsService seems not to work

Tags: wpf, windows-services

I've got a new problem right here:

I've written a small WPF-Application which monitors my TAPI-Lines. On Incoming Calls or Outgoing Calls the program does some Database-Actions. This works really fine so far.
What i want to do now, is a Win-Service which does all of these Actions. Several Employee are login in and out onto the Server where the WPF-App is running. When the User-Session stops, the WPF-App stops too. This is why i've written a Windows Service.

After installing (installutil) and starting the Service from services.msc it seems that the Service is running fine but it isnt. New Incoming/Outgoing Calls doesnt were not written to the Database.

So i asked myself if there are any limitations for those services? Im am using EntityFramework for the Database-Actions and a Telephone-API for monitoring the calls.

While debugging this service everything works just fine... but in "live-mode" nothing works...

Can Anybody give me some tips??
THX

Comment: might sound stupid, but I would recommend you to add logging (a lot) to your service, then you can track down what your service is doing (or not doing)

Comment: Have you debugged the Service attaching the proccess to the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

It propably is a permissions issue.

The service runs per default as user "SYSTEM". In the properties tab of the service you can change this to a user that has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: thank you plaugg... this is a great hint i think. But how can i grant other permissions within this service? Can you tell me that?

Comment: you grant the permissions to the USER that runs the service by e.g. allowing the user to use your database (assuming windows access control).

Comment: I think its not necessary to grant this permissions because i start the service with Domain-Admin. And he's got all permissions which are required i think.

Comment: In Addition to my Answer ive got a ServiceInstaller and a ServiceProcessInstaller in my Service where the Serviceprocess-Account is set to "LocalSystem" which has got unlimited privileges.